# Copy devise users after db:reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rake

I'm currently trying to write a rake task that resets my database while copying admins (specific type of devise user) to the new server.

```
task :safe_reset => :environment do
        desc "Resets db while persisting admins."
        user_collection = []
        User.all.each do |user|
                if user.admin?
                        user_collection << user.attributes
                end
        end
        Rake::Task['db:reset'].invoke
        user_collection.each do |user|
                User.create!(user)
        end
end
```

However, password information is not a public attribute of user. So I don't have enough information to create a new user essentially.

Is there a way to get password information, or preferably, is there a way to do this while avoiding reducing every admin to a hash object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the original password information. But you can get the encrypted password...

Replace

```
    user_collection.each do |user|
            User.create!(user)
    end
```

By this

```
user_collection.each do |user|
  encrypted_password = user.delete('encrypted_password')
  u = User.create!(user.merge({
    :password => "Foobar",
    :password_confirmation => "Foobar"
  })
  u.update_attribute(:encrypted_password, encrypted_password)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be done. Typically an application is 'seeded' (in db/seeds.rb) with one administrative user account. After the application goes live a developer uses that account to propagate the other necessary accounts and changes its details to something other than the defaults. I don't see any advantage or benefit to persisting one table like this as db:reset is generally never used in production or staging and is often used in development. In development we use our seed data to generate accounts for us.

It can be done, depending on your auth solution but I highly recommend against the practice unless there's a good use case for it.